# How do you mathematically express a set of values that are all different?

Tags: notation

Possibly a strange "why would you want to" question, but how do you mathematically express a set of values that are all different?

For example, a set of values for which a mode calculation is impossible due to each element being unique.

Comment: "Pairwise distinct" is a typical phrase that means "no two are the same." I realize that's not a notation. I would not use a notation except in case of absolute necessity (such as programming an automated proof solver).

Comment: I have seen $a\neq b\neq c$ to express that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all different. I don't really like it, since $\neq$ is not transitive.

Comment: Many thanks guys

Comment: It's better to be clear than to be short.  I just write:  Let $\{a_i\}$ be a set of values so that $a_i \ne a_j$ unless $i =j$.  Of course that assumes it's a countable set.  But the term "set" by default means each value is only represented once so it'd be redundant to point it out....  I truly *hate* $a\ne b \ne c$ as $\ne$ is not transitive nor associative and such a string of characters.  If I had a long list (more than $3$) I'd just say "suppose we have $a_1, a_2, ....,a_n$ and they are all pairwise distinct" or "and for any pair $i\ne j$ we have $a_i \ne a_j$"

Answer (score 1):

A set, by definition has unique elements. For e.g., $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ means $x$ is an integer, we don't have to disambiguate further.

Comment: Very very true!  But... there can be a case where one has a *sequence* or a *list* where you want to express the values are distinct.  .... Any answer I know (I'd simply say $a_i \ne a_j$ except when $i=j$) would assume the list or sequences are countable, but then an *un*countable list or sequence is meaningless.

Comment: Not necessarily. For eg: Let $p_k$ be the $k$-th prime. This defines an uncountable sequence. If I say $\mathbb{P} = \{p_k : k \in [0,\infty]\}$, the elements are unambiguous.  In situations like what you describe, we can just define the sequence, say $x_n$ separately and $S$ separately using set builder notation and then say $x_n \in S$ to convey the domain.

Comment: I'm not following.  What is $p_\pi$, the $\pi$th prime?  Certainly a sequence of all primes is countable.  It is a subset of the natural numbers after all.  I'm not certain what you are trying to say. (I don't think we are having a language difficulty about "countable $\ne$ finite", are we?)

Comment: In my previous comment, I didn't specify $k$ is an integer. But that's what was intended.

Comment: I don't understand.  Surely $\{2,3,5,7,11,........\}$ is a countable sequence. (We aren't haven't language translation problems, are we? We both agree that "countable" doesn't mean infinite and that $\mathbb N$ is countable, don't we?)......  Hmmm, I suppose if we had if we had a function $f$ be a real function and we defined $a_x = f(x)$ then we could maybe call $\{a_x|x\in \mathbb R\}$ as an "uncountable sequence" and if $f$ is not injective than it isn't pair-wise distinct.... but I'd consider that a gross abuse of vocabulary.

Comment: Ah, I see. I used uncountable for the sequence of primes when I should have said infinite.